# Control Characters and How OS/TextEditors interprets them?

Tags: windows, operating-system, ascii, computer-science, text-editor

I was going thru some content about control characters especially newline character(will focus on this).After going thru
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_characters, got to know that \n is the line character in unix
while it is \r\n in windows. Now i got the question how OS comes into picture when iterpreting
ASCII Codes becoz i was under impression when we type any given character on keyboard, any OS send the same 
bits and editor interprets that bit and display the corresponding character. **Looks like this understanding is
wrong, Because different bit is sent in case of unix(\n) and windows(\r\n) when we press ENTER(new line terminator).As per
new understanding if we press ENTER on diff OS(say unix and windows),different bits are sent to editor and its
responsibilty of text editor to show the typed stuff in new line keeping the underlying OS in picture.Please let me
know if my understanding is correct as this will help me to understand other basics also?**

Next question is if above is correct, what can be the reason different OS treat some control characters differently
when they treat all other characters equally? Is it becoz specific bits are already reserved in specific OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How an application treats keyboard input varies a bit, actually. When you press return the application is under no obligation to actually generate LF or CR+LF anywhere. E.g. it might decide to just end the current paragraph object and start a new one (e.g. in a word processor). If it's a Windows text editor then it will probably just write CR+LF into the file, while on Unix it just writes an LF.

They keyboard itself is very, very far removed from things you see on the screen or even on the disk. This goes through scan codes, keyboard layouts and other transformations before it ends up as text or markup somewhere.

Comment: Joey. Do you mean to say that all the OS send the same bit for a given character command("Enter" command) from keyboard or OS does not comes into picture at all(Is direct keyboard command is sent to Editor application say editplus without any role of OS in between, now its the responsiblity of editplus which bit needs to be inserted for the given keyboard command. If this is correct why same editor will insert the different bit for the same "Enter" command depending on OS  like on unix it  inserts \n though on window it inserts \r\n )

Comment: If keyboard command directly needs to be interpreted by editor application, it should treat the same keyboard command equally not depending on OS. Is n't it? For example when i press enter, editor should equally insert any given bit whether on unix/windows and interpret it consistently without any dependency on OS

Comment: @MSach The OS has the first take at processing/interpreting the pressed keys. I have multiple keyboard layouts installed on my Windows and pressing the same key 'a' can result in me seeing either of: 'a', 'á', 'à', 'ã', 'â', 'ф' (+ upper case variants of the same), depending on the layout and on whether or not I have pressed something else before or together with 'a' (e.g. 'shift' or 'right alt/altgr', etc). AFAIR, Windows will make the code of the pressed key and the corresponding "character" available to the app. The app can further do anything with the two values, use them as-is or convert.

Comment: @MSach Control codes should not be any different from alphanumeric characters, they are still coming as key codes from the keyboard to the OS and then the OS turns those key codes into whatever is necessary/appropriate. And then the apps can have another round of processing of the keyboard input received from and preprocessed by the OS. Ends of lines being encoded as simply CR or simply LF or a combination of the two are just agreed-upon conventions in whatever system they occur. Some editors support multiple conventions and can even let you choose one.

Comment: Thanks Alexey. I think You should make your comment as answer.